# FILTER formula to display nothing if value is between 2 values Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a FILTER formula to display data based on several conditions:

```
=FILTER('Raw Batter'!I2:K, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B>C4, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5, 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "", 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7 )
```

​​
which works fine, what I am struggling to do is include an IF AND formula within it to  display "" if values are between a range of percentages, like this:

```
('Raw Batter'!I2:I> -10%,'Raw Batter'!I2:I< 10%)
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations and cannot get anything to work...  Any advice would be awesome!

Example sheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j_xGf_vO5sEFakJPfuz2hG-xsgRy8AS2L3KamLsLEQY/edit?usp=sharing

The formula is in I18 of 'Batter" tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER('Raw Batter'!A2:K,
 C4 < 'Raw Batter'!B2:B, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5,
 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "",
 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7,
 'Raw Batter'!I2:I*1> -10%, 'Raw Batter'!I2:I*1< 10%)
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE 1:

```
=FILTER('Raw Batter'!A2:K,
 C4 < 'Raw Batter'!B2:B, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5,
 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "",
 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7,
 ('Raw Batter'!I2:I*1< -10%)+('Raw Batter'!I2:I*1> 10%) )
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE 2:

```
=ArrayFormula({IF((FILTER('Raw Batter'!I2:I*1,
 'Raw Batter'!B2:B>C4, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5,
 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "",
 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7)>10%)+(FILTER('Raw Batter'!I2:I*1,
 'Raw Batter'!B2:B>C4, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5,
 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "",
 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7)<-10%),FILTER('Raw Batter'!I2:I,
 'Raw Batter'!B2:B>C4, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5,
 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "",
 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7), ), FILTER('Raw Batter'!J2:K,
 'Raw Batter'!B2:B>C4, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5,
 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "",
 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7)})
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE 3:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((FILTER('Raw Batter'!I2:I*1,
 'Raw Batter'!B2:B>C4, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5,
 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "",
 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7)>10%)+(FILTER('Raw Batter'!I2:I*1,
 'Raw Batter'!B2:B>C4, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5,
 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "",
 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7)<-10%),FILTER('Raw Batter'!I2:K,
 'Raw Batter'!B2:B>C4, 'Raw Batter'!B2:B < C5,
 'Raw Batter'!D2:D <> "",
 'Raw Batter'!A2:A>=C6,'Raw Batter'!A2:A<=C7), ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks player0! I actually want the opposite to your solution, as in I want to display <-10% or >10% in columns I to J, if I swap the < for > (or vice versa) it results in N/A?

Comment: Im sorry, its my poor explanation. In my original question I mentioned the formula is in cell I18 (as the formula in A18 was fine). The one in I18 need to have the same conditions as the one in A18 BUT if the value in either I18:I or Raw Batter'!I2:I > -10% AND< 10% display "" as in I dont want any percentages between that range to be displayed but still have the empty cell. I hope that makes sense... :)

Comment: So close my friend, thankyou so much for this by the way! I also want the values in column J & K to be "" if the value in column I is between -10% and 10%